# Invalid credentials when Spring Gateway logs in into KeyCloak

Tags: java, keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway

**UPDATED FULL DESCRIPTION**

Hello all again,

I am currently developing a demo prototype to secure a spring service through a Spring Gateway against a Keycloak. In a first step without any security implemented, I created the gateway and was able to redirect the traffic to the service but, unfortunately, as soon as I implemented the security it stopped working.

To my surprise, the gateway part seems to work fine and, after checking the keycloak dashboard,I can see that a client session had been created successfully (which means that my user/password is ok). I have also tested the user/password/client-secret against keycloak using Postman and it correctly returns the token. From my point of view, the gateway works fine.

The problem seems to come from the service part, which triggers the next error and is not even deployed:

```
middleware-tomcat-1      | 2023-06-19T15:21:51.291Z DEBUG 1 --- [           main] swordEncoderAuthenticationManagerBuilder : No authenticationProviders and no parentAuthenticationManager defined. Returning null.
middleware-tomcat-1      | 2023-06-19T15:21:51.432Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/webdemo/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/authentication/BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
middleware-tomcat-1      | 2023-06-19T15:21:51.433Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
middleware-tomcat-1      | 2023-06-19T15:21:51.435Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
middleware-tomcat-1      | 2023-06-19T15:21:51.450Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
middleware-tomcat-1      | 2023-06-19T15:21:51.458Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 
middleware-tomcat-1      | 
middleware-tomcat-1      | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
middleware-tomcat-1      | 2023-06-19T15:21:51.482Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
middleware-tomcat-1      | 
middleware-tomcat-1      | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/webdemo/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/authentication/BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:645) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:174) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:96) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4875) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:713) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:975) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1949) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123) ~[na:na]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:776) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1656) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:898) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:913) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347) ~[bootstrap.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478) ~[bootstrap.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/authentication/BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  ... 60 common frames omitted
middleware-tomcat-1      | Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/authentication/BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.configure(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.java:273) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.configure(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.java:147) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:349) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:303) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at com.webdemo.SecurityConfiguration.filterChain(SecurityConfiguration.java:21) ~[classes/:1.0]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at com.webdemo.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$filterChain$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:1.0]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at com.webdemo.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:1.0]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at com.webdemo.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.filterChain(<generated>) ~[classes/:1.0]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  ... 61 common frames omitted
middleware-tomcat-1      | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1437) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1245) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  ... 77 common frames omitted
middleware-tomcat-1      | 
middleware-tomcat-1      | 19-Jun-2023 15:21:51.488 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/webdemo-1.0.war]
middleware-tomcat-1      |  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:713)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:975)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1949)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:776)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1656)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:913)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
middleware-tomcat-1      |  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/webdemo-1.0]]
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
middleware-tomcat-1      |      ... 37 more
middleware-tomcat-1      |  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/webdemo/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/authentication/BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
```

Following I paste the POM of the SERVICE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demoweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>webdemo</name>
    <description>Demo project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
                
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

 </dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>           
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement> 

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the SERVICE securityconfiguration class that I have been able to gather from several updated sources including official spring documentation:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;


@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()).oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2ResourceServer) -> oauth2ResourceServer.jwt((jwt) -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder())));
        
        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri("http://[KEYCLOAK_IP:PORT]/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs").build();
    } 
}
```

Next are the relevant properties from the SERVICE property file:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://[KEYCLOAK_IP:PORT]/realms/my-realm
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at my tutorials, specially the BFF one https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials

Comment: After several trial and error, I have updated the full description

Comment: For directions to configure (servlet) resource-servers, refer to the dedicated tutorials of the series I already linked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your examples, but I am afraid that, as many others over the internet, they are a bit outdated. For example, in the code " http.csrf().disable();" in the reactive-resource-server, the CSRF part is deprecated. Other tutorials use the "WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter" class, that as stated in "https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter" should be replaced... The code in my SecurityConfiguration have been created with code from official sources, but for some reason I can't make it work...

Comment: In addition to my previous link I had also used this one: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html

Comment: `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` was deprecated in late spring-security 5 versions (boot 2) and removed from security 6 (boot 3), so you won't find a single working spring-boot 3 sample with it. `http.csrf().disable()` was falged deprecated with spring-boot 3.1 one month ago. It is already replaced with `http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())` (as well as all other configurers which should now use exclusively lambdas instead of "fluent" API) but only in the code. I forgot to update readmes, my bad. But, no, samples and tutorials are not outdated: all compile with boot 3.1.0 and without warning.

Comment: Can you add some light to the error in my traces? I cannot make the official spring code work in my SecurityConfiguration out of the box...

Comment: The error could be due to trying to use spring-security 5 with spring-boot 3, but there are other "strange" things like having a dependency on Thymeleaf in a resource server only app. You should probably take some time to read the README at the root of the tutorials (and not try to override the versions already defined by boot)

Comment: You were absolutely right! As soon as I read your comment, I removed all version from my POM and it worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by ch4mp, I was trying to use spring-security 5 with spring-boot 3. As soon as a I removed all version from my POM it worked!